# How can I resolve error 'ext-all.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined' ?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I tried to use ExtJS with a JSON database but I keep getting the same error: `ext-all.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined`.

My script is :

```
 Ext.onReady(function(
    var store=new Ext.data.Store( 
      reader=new Ext.data.JsonReader(        
                            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'category' },
            {name: 'address'},                   
            {name: 'lat'},
            {name: 'long'},
                            {name: 'tel'},
                            {name: 'opening'},
            {name: 'closing'}),
                proxy=new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url : 'http://localhost/progetto/descrittore/json.php'}))
            // method : 'GET'
          })
```

In my HTML I included :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/prova.js"></script>
```

What's causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From classes names I guess that you use Ext JS 3. Correct me if I am wrong.

The problem is that you don't follow the API. `Store` constructor has following signature:

`newExt.data.Store( Object config ) : Object`

You should provide **single** config object. You pass reader and proxy instead. 
Same story with `Reader`. Signature is

`newExt.data.JsonReader( Object meta, Array/Object recordType ) : Object`

You should pass meta data and record definition as array. After correcting this, Ext don't throw exepctions any more. See code below.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var store=new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({}, [     
            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'category' },
            {name: 'address'},                   
            {name: 'lat'},
            {name: 'long'},
            {name: 'tel'},
            {name: 'opening'},
            {name: 'closing'}
        ]),
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url : 'http://localhost/progetto/descrittore/json.php'
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Answered a long time ago, but helped me in my current issue!  Thanks, +1 for you!